# I don't have django_redirect table with migration marked applied though

Tags: django

As I go through django-redirects docs

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
]
```

python manage.py showmigrations

```
 redirects
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_redirect_new_path_help_text
```

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/redirects/redirect/add/

ERROR saying.....

no such table: `django_redirect`

```
\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_redirect
```

Comment: Did you add `SITE_ID = 1` in your setting file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete `0002_alter_redirect_new_path_help_text` file from your project and run the migration command again.

Comment: it works. appreciated!

Comment: can you please mark the question closed?